# normal integer combination

Tags: combinations

How many combinbations can be made of the integers 0-9 using 3 digit combinations?

Comment: Unless you're writing a program to find the answer, this is unfortunately not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

I would try wikipedia entry for [Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).  However to answer your question:

```
120 = (10 * 9 * 8) / (3 * 2 * 1)
```

There are 120 combinations